# Changing a variable with a button (and a function) in Python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter

I have the following code (it's partly in Dutch but I don't think that'll be an issue):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

woorden_en = ["mouse", "armadillo", "caterpillar", "buffalo", "dragonfly", "eel", "monkey", "lark", "manatee", "squid"]
woorden_nl = ["muis", "gordeldier", "rups", "buffel", "libelle", "paling", "aap", "leeuwerik", "zeekoe", "inktvis"]


nummer = IntVar()
nlWoord = StringVar()
enWoord = StringVar()
goedfout = StringVar()

def vorige():
    nummer -= 1
def volgende(): 
    nummer += 1
def controleer():
    print("Correct!")

secondGrid = Frame(root)
secondGrid.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
labelVertaling = Label(root, text="vertaling")
textVertaling = Entry(root, width=30, textvariable = nlWoord)
runVorige = Button(secondGrid, text="vorige", command = vorige)
runVolgende = Button(secondGrid, text="volgende", command = volgende)
runControleer = Button(secondGrid, text="controleer", command = controleer)
labelWoord = Label(root, text="woord")
labelWoordEn = Label(root, textvariable = enWoord)
labelNo = Label(root, textvariable = nummer)
Correct = Label(root, textvariable = goedfout)

Correct.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
labelNo.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
labelWoord.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
labelWoordEn.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
labelVertaling.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
textVertaling.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
runVorige.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "W")
runVolgende.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "W")
runControleer.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = "W")

nummer.set(1)
enWoord.set(woorden_en[0])

root.mainloop()
```

The start value of 'nummer' is 1, as set in the 3rd to last line. This value needs to be changed with either -1 or +1 when clicking buttons 'vorige' (previous) or 'volgende' (next). The current code in the functions give me erros. Apparently I need to use set/get functions, but I cannot find out how to make it work. Any input or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your function to:

```
def vorige():
    nummer_val = nummer.get()
    nummer_val -= 1
    nummer.set(nummer_val)
def volgende():
    nummer_val = nummer.get()
    nummer_val += 1
    nummer.set(nummer_val)
```

This is because `nummer` is an `IntVar()` and you have to get the value of the variable using `get()` method. After that you have to assign it to a variable and then reduce/increase its value by 1. The first error you were getting was because the `nummer` was not globalized inside the function, but that was not the approach you should have taken, anyway this should fix your errors.

Comment: or you can do this without the use of an aux var: `nummer.set(nummer.get()+1)` ect.

Comment: @FlavioMoraes Sure, just wanted to make it easier to understand